# How to change orientation of a specific layout from portrait to landscape such as Framelayout in android.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I built an app that displays my youtube chanel. the problem i am having is to change the orientation to landscape while user presses a full screen button on youtube client. I want that when users select full screen button on youtube the screen automatically switches to landscape view and when user preses the full screen button from landscapr view the orientation would change to portrait but state remains the same. Whole screen must not refreshed again. here is the sample of code that i am using for full screen but it only displays full screen not converting a screen to landscape.

```
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mContentView = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCustomViewContainer.setSystemUiVisibility();
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            // Hide the custom view.
            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
           /* ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mContentView.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeAllViews();
            }*/
            // Show the content view.
            mCustomViewContainer=null;
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            setContentView(mContentView);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in all activity add in manifest this - `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

You can use this for landscape

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

To change to portrait mode, use the

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Edited : 
if you want to rotate view or drawable

rotateAnimationLayout.xml

```
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromDegrees="0" 
       android:toDegrees="-90"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:duration="0"
       android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Code in Activity or Fragment

```
    RotateAnimation rotate= (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotateAnimation);
  yourView.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: i think you didnot understand my question... i dont want to rotate complete activity i only want to rotate a frame layout. is there any way to rotate a specific framelayout to landscape ? without refreshing the whole page

Comment: brother animation is not a proper way... but thanks for your help i found my answer.

Comment: post your ans and approve